# Sending an email with voting buttons using amazon ses

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I am new to AWS SES, so I wanted to know is there a way I can send an email with voting buttons, [like we have in outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXw4R.png), using AWS SES.

Thank You.

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Currently SES doesn't provide any functionality like that but,
Yes it is quite possible to create on your own, and there are numerous ways to do it.

The most basic implementation would be as follows:

1. Since emails are HTML templates, therefore you require a template.
2. In that template you can add buttons depending upon the number of options.
3. Those buttons should be linked to a static link which can record user's input.
4. That link can be a lambda served through an API gateway, which can have multiple queryStringParameters which you can process and store the results.

**For example:**

Link can be like: https://us-east1.lpk39jginkndgk/something?db=nf93n9n&email=d87h82&op=1

In the above example you are getting multiple things:

**db** : It is a DB hash to point to correct db or table where you want your data to store

**email**: Email hash of the receiver

**op** : Option